# android custom listview to zoom

Tags: android, listview

i use custom listview for zoom in and out.
this is custom listview:

```
public class CustomListView1 extends ListView {

private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
private float maxWidth = 0.0f;
private float maxHeight = 0.0f;
private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;
private float width;
private float height;

public CustomListView1(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(),
            new ScaleListener());
}

public CustomListView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(),
            new ScaleListener());
}

public CustomListView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(),
            new ScaleListener());
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);
            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

            mPosX += dx;
            mPosY += dy;

            if (mPosX > 0.0f)
                mPosX = 0.0f;
            else if (mPosX < maxWidth)
                mPosX = maxWidth;

            if (mPosY > 0.0f)
                mPosY = 0.0f;
            else if (mPosY < maxHeight)
                mPosY = maxHeight;

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            invalidate();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    if (mScaleFactor == 1.0f) {
        mPosX = 0.0f;
        mPosY = 0.0f;
    }
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
    invalidate();
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 4.0f));
        maxWidth = width - (width * mScaleFactor);
        maxHeight = height - (height * mScaleFactor);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

this listview can zoom in and out.
but this listview just zoom in the top left corner.
how to fix it to zoom in the center of the pinch?

Comment: Why you want to zoom the listview?

Comment: The listview contain list of image load from url.

Comment: If you want to zoom particular image, then you can set onItemClickListener() on listview. And then you can zoom selected image in diff. activity or in popup. Zooming the listview is bit complicated and not reliable as per UI/UX design standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the code from that other ZoomLayout thing and adapted it to your code.  Just replace the `ScaleListener` class at the bottom with this code:

```
    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float prevScaleFactor = mScaleFactor;
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 4.0f));
            maxWidth = width - (width * mScaleFactor);
            maxHeight = height - (height * mScaleFactor);

            float adjustedScaleFactor = mScaleFactor / prevScaleFactor;
            float focusX = detector.getFocusX();
            float focusY = detector.getFocusY();
            mPosX += (mPosX - focusX) * (adjustedScaleFactor - 1);
            mPosY += (mPosY - focusY) * (adjustedScaleFactor - 1);

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
```